# Cinnamon hot corners on second display

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

I have two displays. I was able to add a second panel on the new display but my hot corners are not carrying over. I don't see any option anywhere to enable this functionality.

Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 2.6.13.